# Change color of a rectangle inside SVG

Tags: python, svg

I have a problem. I want to color a certain rectangle. For example the rectangle with the text `task12` should be get a different color. How could I do that?

The problem of my code is that it runs without an error but nothing happend.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pydot
from IPython.display import SVG

def colorize_svg_text(svg_file, text, color):
    # Parse the SVG file
    tree = ET.parse(svg_file)
    print(tree)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Find the text element with the specified text
    
    text_elements = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}text")
    for text_element in text_elements:
        if text_element.text == text:
            # Find the parent group element
            parent_group = text_element.getparent()

            # Find the rectangle element within the parent group
            rect_element = parent_group.find(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}rect")
            if rect_element is not None:
                # Set the fill color of the rectangle
                rect_element.set("fill", color)

    # Write the modified SVG file
    tree.write(svg_file)
    SVG(svg_file)

colorize_svg_text("./process.svg", "task1", "#FF0000")
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Do not edit this file with editors other than diagrams.net -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="586px" height="110px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 586 110"
    content="&lt;mxfile host=&quot;app.diagrams.net&quot; modified=&quot;2023-05-16T11:56:06.977Z&quot; agent=&quot;Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0&quot; etag=&quot;-GX8pC0S9O5ZFpbGgMyz&quot; version=&quot;21.3.1&quot; type=&quot;device&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram name=&quot;Seite-1&quot; id=&quot;BNIXbyRiX4PgmjJBz96H&quot;&gt;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&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;">
    <defs />
    <g>
        <path d="M 60.04 66.37 L 60.04 80.04 L 60.31 93.27" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10"
            pointer-events="stroke" />
        <path d="M 60.04 61.12 L 63.54 68.12 L 60.04 66.37 L 56.54 68.12 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <path d="M 60.42 98.52 L 56.78 91.6 L 60.31 93.27 L 63.78 91.45 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="120" height="60" fill="#f5f5f5" stroke="#666666" pointer-events="all" />
        <g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
            <switch>
                <foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%"
                    height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 1px;">
                        <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;"
                            data-drawio-colors="color: #333333; ">
                            <div
                                style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; font-weight: bold; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">
                                <div>task12</div>
                                <div>days<br /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </foreignObject><text x="60" y="34" fill="#333333" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px"
                    text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold">task12...</text>
            </switch>
        </g>
        <path d="M 525 66.37 L 525 80.04 L 526.28 80.04 L 525.95 93.27" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" />
        <path d="M 525 61.12 L 528.5 68.12 L 525 66.37 L 521.5 68.12 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <path d="M 525.82 98.52 L 522.5 91.44 L 525.95 93.27 L 529.49 91.61 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <rect x="465" y="0" width="120" height="60" fill="#f5f5f5" stroke="#666666" pointer-events="all" />
        <g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
            <switch>
                <foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%"
                    height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 466px;">
                        <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;"
                            data-drawio-colors="color: #333333; ">
                            <div
                                style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; font-weight: bold; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">
                                <div>task14</div>
                                <div>days<br /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </foreignObject><text x="525" y="34" fill="#333333" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px"
                    text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold">task14...</text>
            </switch>
        </g>
    </g>
    <switch>
        <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" /><a transform="translate(0,-5)"
            xlink:href="https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/svg-export-text-problems" target="_blank"><text
                text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Text is not SVG - cannot display</text></a>
    </switch>
</svg>
```

The output should be
[image]